# window is close when double click on datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, linq-to-sql, wpfdatagrid

i have a data grid which is bind with data source. i set isReadOnly="False" property to edit. when i click on cell then an exception occur. 
Xaml code :-

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Fee Head" Width="250" Binding="{Binding feename}" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount(Rs.)" Width="250" Binding="{Binding NewAmount}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Hidden" Header="cnt" Width="10" Binding="{Binding id}"/>


            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

.cs code :-

```
 var obje = (from tab in cd.FeeDeclarationDetails
                                             join tab2 in cd.AccountHeadDBs on tab.AccountHeaddbid equals tab2.ID
                                             where tab.AccountHeaddbid == tab2.ID
                                             select new { feename = tab2.Head_Name, tab.NewAmount, cnt = (cd.FeeDeclarationDetails.Where(A => A.AccountHeaddbid == 1 && A.FeeDeclarationID == 1).ToList().Count > 0 ? cd.FeeDeclarationDetails.Where(A => A.AccountHeaddbid == 1 && A.FeeDeclarationID == 1).ToList().Count : 0) }).ToList();

                    dataGrid1.ItemsSource = obje;
```

i am using linq2sql. and exception is:- A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'NewAmount' of type '<>f__AnonymousType6`3[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32],System.Int32]'.so how can i solve this problem.

Comment: As the exception says, you get it because the `Model` you want to display has one or more read-only properties. You can get rid of the exception by adding a `...,Mode=OneWay}` to the 'Binding' expression(s) referring to those properties.

Comment: i am working on window form and if i m adding Mode="OneWay" then cell is not editable. and set "TwoWay" then exception occur

Comment: You are right, but the problem in that case is that the "Model" you created by your current design is not able to do what you want, because a read-only property just cannot be edited. And the next (or previous) question could be how to get the edited Model back into the back-end DB. I think unfortunately your actual question might be too big to fit into a single forum question or reply, would suggest to read a few of the countless getting-started web articles on the MVVM pattern first.

Answer (score 0):

Your Property 'NewAmount'of Type FeeDeclarationDetails seems to be read-only property.. make sure it has a setter ..